# Palabra o expresión para definir un lapsus que podría indicar lo que realmente se piensa

Tags: selección-de-palabras, solicitud-de-término, solicitud-de-modismo

<sub>Sigamos con [*single-word-requests*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests) de English Language & Usage. Vayamos a por otra [petición de palabra](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/petici%C3%B3n-de-palabra) o [modismo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/petici%C3%B3n-de-modismo) basándonos en [*Word meaning: A slip of the tongue which suggests how you actually feel, often humorous*](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/309693/37429).</sub>

A veces uno está hablando y de repente dice algo cuando quería decir otra cosa, como [por ejemplo George Bush](https://lamenteesmaravillosa.com/los-lapsus-un-tema-serio-y-divertido-a-la-vez/):

> Nuestros enemigos son innovadores e ingeniosos, y nosotros también.
>   Nunca dejan de pensar en nuevos métodos para perjudicar a nuestro país
>   y a nuestro pueblo, ni nosotros tampoco.

Pero esto incluso se usa a veces en plan divertido:

> - Ha sido un placer conocerle
>   - Igual miente (por *igualmente*)

Tanto [en inglés](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/309730/37429) cono en castellano usamos la palabra *lapsus*. En inglés, sin embargo, tienen la expresión [Freudian slip](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/309695/37429) a estos casos en los que, según cómo, lo que se dice es lo que se querría haber dicho pero no se dice por educación, convención o lo que sea.

¿Tenemos en castellano alguna expresión o palabra análoga?

Comment: Sólo porque riman: `lapsus pendejus` o `lapsus matutinus` ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Al igual que *Freudian slip* en inglés, en español yo he oído varias veces ***[lapsus](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Mven5SH) [freudiano](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ITbsvqV)***.

El Diccionario panhispánico de dudas también propone [***lapsus línguae***](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=L6B8d2XCeD6tFquJfy):

> Se emplea como locución nominal masculina con el sentido de ‘error
>   involuntario que se comete al hablar’: «Un lapsus línguae, la
>   inoportuna confusión de una palabra con otra, es con frecuencia muy
>   reveladora de intenciones o preocupaciones reprimidas»

Comment: Interesantísimo. Qué curioso además que sea _línguae_. Al decirlo, yo siempre ponía la tónia en la _a_, así que esta tilde es esclarecedora. Por cierto, benvingut a [spanish.se]!

Comment: @fedorqui Gràcies! La RAE también contiene [lapsus linguae](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MvluEsL), sin tilde.

Answer (score 9):

La expresión es *[acto fallido](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acto_fallido)*. Al igual que *Freudian slip* en inglés, no se reduce únicamente a errores orales, como muestra [esta definición](http://www.cun.es/diccionario-medico/terminos/acto-fallido) en el sitio de la Clínica Universidad de Navarra:

> Errores, equivocaciones, olvidos momentáneos, pérdidas de objetos, debidos generalmente a la distracción, el cansancio o la excitación. Según la teoría psicoanalítica, los actos fallidos son actos sintomáticos: el sujeto, por la influencia perturbadora de ideas o deseos inconscientes, expresa involuntariamente, de forma figurada, lo que en realidad intenta callar y encubrir.

Al menos en Argentina, país con fuerte influencia psicoanalítica en la cultura, cuando se trata de un error oral se suele abreviar simplemente como *fallido*. Ejemplos:

- [El fallido de Macri: "Me llevó un motochorro..."](http://www.minutouno.com/notas/130531-el-fallido-macri-me-llevo-un-motochorro)
- [El contundente fallido de Luis Delía: “La corrupción es estructural en este partido”](http://plusya.com.ar/video-el-contundente-fallido-de-luis-delia-la-corrupcion-es-estructural-en-este-partido/)
- [Dólares, cedines, inmuebles... y el fallido de Cristina](http://tn.com.ar/politica/dolares-cedines-inmuebles-y-el-fallido-de-cristina_522545)